# Event registration: adding guest names later

Tags: civievent

The use case is that we need to allow people to buy tables of ten at a lunch event, but not have to submit the guest names until much closer to the event. I can get some of the way by having a price set with an option to increment the participant count by 10. But I can't then see how to input the 9 actual guest names at a later date, and keeping the total participant count at 10, and the contribution amount unchanged. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

We're in the process of building an extension to do exactly this, will share it when complete (it relies on some drupal specific functions at the moment but could probably be made CMS agnostic without too much effort).

Comment: Thank so much for this good news. Do you have an expected date when it might available (even for testing by others)? Do you need additional funding to complete this faster?

Comment: We have a version specific for a client and plan to make it more generic. Funding would speed up the process if its available

Comment: I've sent you a message on chat.civicrm. Can you make contact with me offline?

Comment: @ParvezSaleh was this extension ever made? and if so is there a version for Joomla?