# Event Registration: adding guest names

Tags: civievent, participants

My question is similar to this one from 2020 but didn't seem to be a fix then: [Event registration: adding guest names later](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/event-registration-adding-guest-names-later)

Essentially, I want to see how I can add guest names to a purchase that has multiple participants in one purchase both for the guest to do during purchase, or for me to go back and add later.

**USE CASES**

**Individual tickets:** I am buying tickets for myself and my husband, I want to be able to add my husbands name as my guest.

**Sponsorship:** My sponsorship comes with 4 tickets but I am going to tell you their names later, how can I add them as guests to the company later in a way that is easy to run a participant report to know what guests are with what company.

**NOTE:** I know I could just add a custom field for guest names. But my dream hope is that instead it could be a function where if they put in the guest's name and email it could run a rule in backend to log against a contact if they already exist. And that depending on the number of guests, that number of profile fields would show.

Similar to the functionality that turns on when you allow for multiple registrations at once, but without each guest having to make a separate purchase.

If it matters due to a recommended extension and/or a webform recommendation, I am using Joomla.